# Vagrant plugin doesn't work in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, virtualbox, jenkins-plugins, vagrant

I install vagrant plugin in Jenkins (ubuntu12.04) and when I try to build, I am getting the below errors.

```
Started by user anonymous

Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/testvagrant/workspace

Running Vagrant with version: 1.0.2.dev

FATAL: (ArgumentError) wrong number of arguments calling initialize (1 for 0)
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ArgumentError) wrong number of arguments calling initialize (1 for 0)
    at RUBY.initialize(/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/vagrant/WEB-INF/classes/vendor/gems/jruby/1.8/bundler/gems/vagrant-8a5b1ad0d1ef/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:77)
    at RUBY.setup(/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/vagrant/WEB-INF/classes/models/vagrant_wrapper.rb:63)
    at RUBY.setUp(/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/vagrant/WEB-INF/classes/vendor/gems/jruby/1.8/gems/jenkins-plugin-runtime-0.1.26/lib/jenkins/model/environment_proxy.rb:7)
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Looking forward to your reply.

Thanks

Comment: Stack overflow isn't the best place to ask this, as it looks like a bug in the plugin. Post an issue on the [Github page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/vagrant-plugin)

Comment: I also note that the Jenkins/Vagrant plugin hasn't been updated since Spring 2012 - there are likely quite a few compatibility issues between now and then.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins-Vagrant plugin uses a forked version of Vagrant at [version 1.0.2.dev](https://github.com/jenkinsci/vagrant-plugin/commit/58fc9c4808cf1ffc2bac0ee89540fc9fb4286106).

This version is not compatible with Vagrant's version 2 [config format](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/version.html).

If you try with a version 1 Vagrantfile it might work, but that precludes you from using plugins like vagrant-aws.